# Chrome will not open uri handler when passed as argument

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, pidgin, spotify

I'm using Pidgin and by default all URI handlers are sent to the default browser, which is Chrome in my case.

If I click on a spotify URI chrome opens with a blank window. This also happens if from a run dialog I do `chrome spotify:artist:7w5hVyH6GGdmswqTwHplgF`. Now, if I enter this address in the URL bar myself and hit enter it works.

Is there any way to have chrome pass the custom URI when run via commandline?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
spotify.exe --uri=spotify:album:37lWyRxkf3wQHCOlXM5WfX
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Custom URIs not being followed in the Omnibox or when passed as a command line parameter is [known issue 560809 in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=560809).

As of writing the issue does not describe any workarounds :/